# Django DateTImeField format is lost when edit form

Tags: python, django, forms, datetime

I have something like this in form :

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    reg_due_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'datePicker','readonly':'true'}))
```

and

```
class Event(models.Model):
    reg_due_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Everything is ok, when I use jQuery DateTimePicker I have correct datetime format in the input field. But when I try to edit the form via this part of code I see seconds appearing and it is totally unacceptable. Where it comes from?

```
def editEventInfo(request,event_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if event_id:
            event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
            form = EventForm(instance=event) # An unbound form
        else:
            form = EventForm() # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('events/editEvent.html', {
            'form': form,
        },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_formats` is the list of formats the form field will use to parse the input string into a date, what's printed is driven by the format localization.

you either need to activate `USE_L10N = True` or override `DATETIME_FORMAT`

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#datetime-format

Comment: It did not work because the DATETIME_FORMAT for the locale you use has seconds, if you don't like the format set USE_L10N to False and specify DATETIME_FORMAT in your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

The answer above didn't solve my problem, 
I had to override the default DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS and put my format up top, because django selects the format as soon as it matches in tuple.

After i put this in settings and my custom format high in priority, it rendered correctly.

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06')
```